# Ajax With Django Not Reload Page But Loop will reload

Tags: django, ajax, web, django-views, django-templates

```
<div class="container" id="cd">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-2">
            <label for="serialno" class="h4 text-center mx-4"> S.No </label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-3">
            <label for="billno" class="h4 text-center"> Bill No</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-5">
            <label for="Items" class="h4 text-center"> Items</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-2">
            <label for="total" class="h4 text-center"> Total</label>
        </div>
        <hr>
    </div>
    {% for b,d in history.items %}
    <div class="row" id="refresh">
        <div class="col-2 py-2">
            <label class="h6">{{forloop.counter}}. | {{b.created_at}}</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-3 py-2">
            <label class="h5">{{b}}</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-5 py-2">
            {% for i in d %}
            <label class="h6">{{i.itemname}} x {{i.qty}} {{i.subtotal}}</label><br>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
        <div class="col-2 py-2">
            <span class="h6">&#8377;</span>
            <label class="h6">{{b.grandtotal}}</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

```
<script>
    $(document).on('change','#myform',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:"{% url 'history' %}",
                data:{
                    tb1:$('#cal').val(),
                    csrfmiddlewaretoken:$('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),
                },
                success:function(response){
                    
                },
        });
    });
    </script>
```

How Can I reload this {% for b,d in history.items() %} without refresh a page using ajax
Any way to change history value using ajax Important Note value processed by onchange event

I am trying to reload the loop without a page reload

I want to change the history.items() django variable value after the ajax call and corressponding values can be iterated

Answer (score 0):

```
{% for b,d in history.items %}
<div class="row" id="refresh-main">
    <div class="row" id="refresh-child">    

        <div class="col-2 py-2">
            <label class="h6">{{forloop.counter}}. | {{b.created_at}}</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-3 py-2">
            <label class="h5">{{b}}</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-5 py-2">
            {% for i in d %}
            <label class="h6">{{i.itemname}} x {{i.qty}} {{i.subtotal}}</label><br>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
        <div class="col-2 py-2">
            <span class="h6">&#8377;</span>
            <label class="h6">{{b.grandtotal}}</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

```
<script>
    $(document).on('change','#myform',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:"{% url 'history' %}",
                data:{
                    tb1:$('#cal').val(),
                    csrfmiddlewaretoken:$('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),
                },
                success:function(response){
                    var pageURL = $(location).attr("href");
                    $('#refresh-main').load(pageURL + ' #refresh-child'); 
                },
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Oh well thanks for your answer it gets the particular query set but not change this {{% for b,d in history.items %}} I want to update the history variable value I doesn't change the history value